# mTLS auth fails, unclear why

Tags: openssl, microsoft-edge, smartcard, client-certificates, mtls

I'm trying to implement smartcard login on my website. I have NodeJS and my own CA to generate the client cert.

Everything works when the cert is imported in the cert store on the client PC, I can authenticate with that setup. When I try to use the same cert imported into a V3 smartcard:

- The browser IS able to get the cert
- TLS shows the following, the communications and this error occur maybe 5 times between when I load the page and enter the card pin (fatal but communication restarts afterwards with ClientHello):

```
    Received Record
    Header:
      Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
      Content Type = ChangeCipherSpec (20)
      Length = 1
    Received Record
    Header:
      Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
      Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
      Length = 25
      Inner Content Type = Handshake (22)
        Certificate, Length=4
          context (len=0): 
          certificate_list, length=0
    
    Sent Record
    Header:
      Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
      Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
      Length = 19
      Inner Content Type = Alert (21)
        Level=fatal(2), description=unknown(116)
```

- TLS eventually shows user cert + issuer cert are sent to the server:

  ```
  Inner Content Type = Handshake (22)
  Certificate
  ```
- BUT directly after that, **client** sends `Level=fatal(2), description=handshake failure(40)`

So why does client send handshake failure, just after it sent over the certs?? I am pretty sure certs are fine locally, this succeeds:

```
openssl s_client -connect website.com:443 -prexit -cert usercert.pem -key userkey.pem -CAfile fullchain.pem -pass pass:12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the answer was to disable TLSv1.3...V3 applet cards (as opposed to MD cards) don't support some cipher suite from TLSv1.3. I haven't checked which in any detail.